# how to start lein with an existing clojure jar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to download/install/run clojure/lein and facing some initial problems. I am using cygwin on windows-7.

After downloading the latest clojure (1.8.0), the following step works fine:

```
java -cp clojure-1.8.0.jar clojure.main
```

Now I installed lein using the following steps (thanks to stackoverflow/18711805 for help):

```
download lein script into ~/bin , set filetype=unix
install wget and deps (see stackoverflow/18711805)
setenv HTTP_CLIENT "wget --no-check-certificate -O"
lein self-install
```

Now when I run "lein repl", I find that lein has downloaded another clojure version (1.7.0) and using that.

So, how can I ask lein to use my version of clojure (ie 1.8.0) and not the 1.7.0 ? Are there any extra environment variables to be set before the lein run?

Also, where does lein install its extra downloads, and how do I clean up that area?

Comment: Have you checked project.clj?  You can specify which version you want there.

Comment: where can I find project.clj? The "getting started" tutorial (at http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/getting_started.html) also says not to install clojure directly, and lein will do it for me. So how do I tell lein to download 1.8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

"lein upgrade" did the trick, I got the hint from stackoverflow/24094597. Now when I run lein again I can see 1.8.0 (not my own install, but lein has installed this new version). But since I installed lein just a few minutes ago from scratch anyway, I am not sure why it did not install the latest version in the first place.